# Regular expression: match value from HTML tag without spaces and line breaks

Tags: regex

I have HTML tag like `<span class="value">
                            0,0126                    </span>`, also with a comma or point as separator or decimal character, line break, 28 spaces before and after the number.

I want to **match only the number with or without comma and/or point** - like `1`, `0,123` or `123.456,78`.

I tried it with `<span class="value">(.*)</span>` and with `<span="value">[^\s-]</span>`- without success.

In the HTML code where the regex should match, is only one unique `<span class="value">...</span>`.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser, don't use regex. Also, `.` doesn't match `\n`

Comment: @ctwheels :) i would, but... a parser is for this task a nuclear overkill....

Comment: Then use `<span class="value">(.*?)</span>` with `s` (single-line/dot all) flag or use `<span class="value">([\s\S]*?)</span>`

Comment: @ctwheels you are the man ;) `<span class="value">([\s\S]*?)</span>` works like a charm!

Comment: `want to match only the number with or without comma and/or point` where is this in your regex attempt ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have tabs instead of spaces. Could you try to check if it works: `<span="value">[\s\t]*(\S+)[\s\t]*</span>`

The regex will ignore all tabs and spaces before and after the number.

Comment: `\s` will match tabs. The issue is that `.` doesn't match `\n`